# Seleccionar a todos los hijos de un elemento padre

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

Tengo un div con el id "Padre" y dentro tengo muchos elementos repartidos en distintos niveles de jerarquia, pero todos esos elementos tienen la clase "hijo".

Aclaro, lo necesito de esta forma porque los elementos dentro de la clase padre se crearán con Ajax, y lo que necesito es añadirle cosas a esas clases, pero como son elementos nuevos un simple **querySelectorAll(".hijos")** no lo captura ya que esos elementos no existen al cargar la pagina, por lo que quiero mediante un elemento padre que nunca cambia seleccionarlos nuevamente para añadirle eventos a esas clases

¿Como podria seleccionar a todos los hijos de ese padre?

```html
<div class="padre">
        <div class="alt">
            <div class="uno">
                <div class="hijo"></div>
                <div class="dos">
                    <div class="hijo"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="alt">
            <div class="tres">
                <div class="cuatro">
                    <div class="cinco">
                        <div class="hijo"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hijo">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Esto obvio con JS o Jquery.

Comment: Hola, la forma mas rapida es con algo asi:
```
const $hijos = document.querySelectorAll(".hijo")
```
Te va a devolver un array con todas las divs con clase "hijo"
Es eso lo que buscabas?

Comment: utilizando `querySelectorAll('.padre .hijo');` o también puedes utilizar `getElementsByClassName('.padre .hijo');`

Answer (score 0):

Estás usando una CLASE padre, no un ID, como indicaste en tu problema, si lo que quieres es específicamente retornar los hijos que están dentro de un identificador padre, puedes usar alguna función que reviste todos los hijos y los guarde dentro de un arreglo, no sé si exista una forma más sencilla de hacerlo, pero esto es lo que se me ocurrió a mí

```js
const myElement = document.getElementById('padre');

const hijosArray = []

findHijos(myElement.children)

console.log(hijosArray.length)

function findHijos(childrenArray){
    for (const element of childrenArray) {
    if(element.className === "hijo"){
        hijosArray.push(element)
    }
    if(element.children.length > 0){
        findHijos(element.children)
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="padre">
        <div class="alt">
            <div class="uno">
                <div class="hijo"></div>
                <div class="dos">
                    <div class="hijo"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="alt">
            <div class="tres">
                <div class="cuatro">
                    <div class="cinco">
                        <div class="hijo"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hijo">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `querySelectorAll` después de terminada la llamada *Ajax* para tener acceso a los elementos que recién agregaste.

En el ejemplo a continuación estoy simulando una llamada Ajax que devuelve directamente el HTML que se agrega al div padre, que originalmente es lo único que se encuentra en el documento.

Al resolverse la llamada, se agrega el contenido e inmediatamente después se utiliza `querySelectorAll()` para obtener un arreglo de los elementos, por el que se itera para imprimir el ID de cada uno.

Para simular la llamada he dejado un botón al que hay que hacer clic.

```js
function simularLlamadaAjax() {
  const contenido = `
  <div class="alt">
    <div class="uno">
      <div id="hijo1" class="hijo"></div>
      <div class="dos">
        <div id="hijo2" class="hijo"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="alt">
    <div class="tres">
      <div class="cuatro">
        <div class="cinco">
          <div id="hijo3" class="hijo"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="hijo4" class="hijo">
  </div>
  `;  
  return Promise.resolve(contenido);
}

function agregarContenido() {
  simularLlamadaAjax().then((value) => {
    let padre = document.getElementById("padre");
    padre.innerHTML = value;
    document.querySelectorAll(".hijo").forEach((el) => {
      console.log(el.id);
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="padre" class="padre">
</div>
<button onClick="agregarContenido()">Simular llamada Ajax</button>
```

El ejemplo obtiene de la supuesta llamada ajax directamente el HTML, pero la idea es aplicable aunque el Ajax devuelva datos y este HTML sea producto de un proceso que se haga con los datos. Lo importante es que la llamada funciona una vez se ha agregado el HTML (sea dentro del div padre o no).